# How to check if the record exist using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I'm creating a registration form using codeigniter. I understand that there is a validation for each field in CI but what I want to do is to validate a multiple field exist.

```
SELECT emp_id FROM emp_record WHERE firstname = 'firstname' AND lastname = 'firstname'   AND birthdate = 'firstname'
```

If the query above find a match I want to alert on my view page that the record already exist.

Please help.

Appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a custom callback function

```
function _check_firstname()
{
    $firstname = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('firstname'));
    $array = array('firstname' => $firstname, 'birthdate' => $firstname);
    $result = $this->db->select('emp_id')->from('emp_record')->where($array)->get();
    if($result->num_rows())
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('_check_firstname', 'Record already exists');
        return false;
    }else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Set rules including (`callback__check_firstname`)

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'First Name', 'trim|required|callback__check_firstname');
```

Now, when you'll check validation like

```
if ($this->form_validation->run()){
    // passes
}
else{
    // not passes, so show the view again
}
```

In the view, if you have something like this

```
<?php echo form_error('firstname') ?>
```

This will show the error message set in the custom callback function.

Answer (score 0):

You could use num_rows() to do such things.
By using active record you can achieve this by doing the following

```
$qry = $this->db->select('emp_id')->from('emp_record')
            ->where('firstname', $firstname)
            ->where('lastname', $lastname)
            ->where('birthdate', $birthdate)
            ->get();

if ($qry->num_rows() > 0)
     return TRUE;
else
     return FALSE;
```

This will return TRUE if it finds at least one row in your database or FALSE if it finds nothing.

Answer (score 0):

some people can/may have the same firstname,lastname and birthdate

But still if you want to have it that way you could create a `callback validation`

here is a snippet.

```
public function checkinput()
{
  // you may want to sanitize the input
  $data['fname'] = $this->input->post('fname');
  $data['lname'] = $this->input->post('fname');
  $data['mname'] = $this->input->post('fname');

  //your model for checking data must return TRUE or FALSE
  if($this->model->method_for_checking($data))
  {
    this->form_validation->set_message('checkinput', 'Duplicate data exists.');
    return TRUE;
  }else{
    return FALSE;
  }
}
```

Now you can use it on your validation rules i.e

`$this->form_validation('fname','fname',callback_checkinput);`

Other options are

1. Extend a form validation and create a validation rule there as not
   to clutter the controller
2. Or ,After Submitting the form before inserting the data, you can check whether it is a         duplicate and do the logical things their.